# Forcing Jaxb preference of union member type when compiling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I am compiling an XSD using xjc that includes the following type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CPT-DateTime">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>Can be specified as a integer number or as xs:dateTime</xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:unsignedLong xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The resulting classes that use this type are compiled with this element set as String, while I would prefer them to use XMLGregorianCalendar.

Is there a way to that would force xjc to pick the xs:dateTime member type over the String? I've seen how to do this for [simple types](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html) but not unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe*, what [you've referenced](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html) should actually work for arbitrary simple types. Assuming `tns` is a declared prefix for the targen namespace in your schema, try the following mapping:

```
<globalBindings>
    <javaType name="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar" xmlType="tns:CPT-DateTime" .../>
</globalBindings>
```

However, I am not 100% sure.

Also check [`xjc:javaType`](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#javaType).

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here [xjc: override xs:simpleType definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239406/xjc-override-xssimpletype-definition)

[`javaType` won't work because `XMLGregorianCalendar` is abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239406/xjc-override-xssimpletype-definition#comment43028272_27244196).  I'm headed down the path of adding a small adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes courtesy of denishaskin's final implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings jxb:version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="{NS1-n}" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
<jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema" schemaLocation="../{SCHEMA}.xsd">
<jxb:globalBindings>
<jxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime"/>
<jxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime" xmlType="tns:CPT-DateTime"/>
<jxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalDate" xmlType="tns:CPT-Date"/>
<jxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalTime" xmlType="tns:CPT-Time"/>
</jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```