# xjc: override xs:simpleType definition

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I am compiling a set of XSDs to Java classes using `xjc`.  I would like to be able to override the data type definition for a given simple type.  The XSD snippet is:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CPT-DateTime">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>Can be specified as a integer number or as xs:dateTime</xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:unsignedLong xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

which results (not surprisingly) in an element of the `CPT-DateTime` type being defined in the resulting Java class as a `String`, e.g.

```
public class CcReportTrainInitialization {
...
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String time;
...
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String value) {
        this.time = value;
    }
...
```

What I would like is for the datatype of `time` (in this example) to be a date-time specific type, e.g. `XMLGregorianCalendar` or something like that:

```
public class CcReportTrainInitialization {
...
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar time;
...
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.time = value;
    }
...
```

Is this possible?

I've been experimenting with a binding file but I'm not sure it's even possible to do.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further options are:

- [`jaxb:baseType`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148590)
- [`jaxb:javaType`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148613)
- [`xjc:javaType`](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#javaType) - like `jaxb:javaType` but allows specifying the adapter class instead of `unmarshal`/`marshal` methods.

I would actually argue that `jaxb:class/@ref` customization is not right for the simple type as this makes it a "class" type. This matters for the internal XJC model, some of the XJC plugins may handle your type incorrectly.

I think you should use `jaxb:javaType` here. Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings jxb:version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="urn:your-target-namespace">
  <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema" schemaLocation="../TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
      <jxb:javaType name="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar" xmlType="tns:CPT-DateTime"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: I think that's the right track, although using `jxb:javaType` I get `error: XMLGregorianCalendar is abstract; cannot be instantiated` in the generated adapter source, which makes sense.  I'm trying `xjc:javaType` but its unclear whether I need to write my own adapter class for that or there's an existing one that will/can be used.

Comment: To be more precise: it seems like there should be some way I can write a bindings file that would map from `tns:CPT-DateTime` to `XMLGregorianCalendar` without me having to write an adapter class...

Answer (score 3):

This was actually remarkably easy once I found the right incantation; here's the bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings jxb:version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema" schemaLocation="../TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='CPT-DateTime']">
      <jxb:class ref="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```