# Customizing JAXB classes

Tags: xml, eclipse, jaxb, eclipselink

I have created JAXB classes from an XSD but have noticed that some of the classes have setters 
where the parameter is `Object`. Looking into the XSD, it appears that this could be down to a missing data type definition for the element. I'm *guessing* that as there is no data type definition, JAXB is defaulting the setter's parameter to `Object`. Some (not all) of these elements also have the fixed value set so may explain why the data type is not provided in the XSD.

An example of one of the elements is

`<xs:element name="DefaultCar" fixed="XXXX"/>`

I want to overide JAXB using `Object` as the parameter and use for example, `String`. I've had partial success with an external binding customization file. Although the class's setter parameter is set to what I have specified, the @XmlElement has been given a `type = Object.class` and therefore overiding the setter's parameter. Is it possible to prevent JAXB from placing `type = Object.class` for the @XmlElement?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="Car", propOrder = {
    "defaultCar"
} 

public class Car {
  @XmlElement(name = "DefaultCar", type = Object.class) 
  protected String defaultCar;  

  public void setDefaultCar(String value) {
    this.defaultCar = value;
}
```

Comment: Post the code of one of the classes. There's normally a description in the Javadoc of why you get `Object`.

Comment: @lexicore, the code for one of the classes is in my question - the last highlighted section. Is this what you want to see? Any ideas where I can get access to the Javadoc? I'm using Eclipse and generate the JAXB classes from the Wizard. I assumed `Object` is given because there is no data type defined for the element in the XSD. Thx.

Comment: So this is what you have in the generated source code? No JavaDoc comments? Strange. But try suggestions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239406/xjc-override-xssimpletype-definition/27244196#27244196) question. If nothing helps, you can override annotations with [tag:jaxb2-annotate-plugin] but that's the last thing to do.

Comment: @lexicore, I do have comments in the generated JAXB classes but didn't realise the comments were JavaDoc comments - sorry my bad. The comments weren't of any help anyway. Your pointer to [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239406/xjc-override-xssimpletype-definition/27244196#27244196) solved my problem. I had already tried `jaxb:baseType` and `jaxb:javaType` with no luck but `jaxb:class ref` did the trick. Thx for picking up my question.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept your answer later on, thank you for posting the solution you've found out.

Answer (score 1):

Within the external binding customization file, I used `jxb:class ref="java.lang.String"` under the `jxb:bindings` node. The suggestion from [xjc: override xs:simpleType definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239406/xjc-override-xssimpletype-definition/27244196#27244196) pointed me in the right direction.